# Not able to get randomness on unit test

Tags: substrate-node, unit-tests, randomness

I'm building a pallet that requires some randomness to simulate the act of tossing a coin. That's why I'm following the same implementation as provided on the *[Lottery pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/lottery/src/lib.rs)*. Particularly, the following method:

```rust
    pub fn generate_insecure_random_boolean(seed: u32) -> bool {
        let pallet_id = T::PalletId::get();
        let (random_seed, _) = T::Randomness::random(&(pallet_id, seed).encode());
        let random_number = <u32>::decode(&mut random_seed.as_ref())
            .expect("secure hashes should always be bigger than u32; qed");
        random_number % 2 == 0
    }
```

That generates a random number based on the `PalletId` and the value of a particular seed, which in my case, is given by the `current block number`:

```rust
    pub fn random_coin_side() -> CoinSide {
        let block_number = <frame_system::Pallet<T>>::block_number();
        let seed = block_number.try_into().unwrap_or_else(|_| 0u32);

        if Self::generate_insecure_random_boolean(seed) {
            // println!("Coin side: Head");
            CoinSide::Head
        } else {
            // println!("Coin side: Tail");
            CoinSide::Tail
        }
    }
```

This works perfectly when testing the node running through PolkadotJS, I do see the randomness and how the coin is flipped randomly.

However, my problem is when I test this function on my unit test suite. ***I'm always getting the same random number, even if I'm setting current block number explicitly to update the seed used***. Here is my unit test:

```rust
    #[test]
    fn toss_coin_works() {
        new_test_ext().execute_with(|| {
            assert_ok!(CoinGame::create_coin(RuntimeOrigin::signed(ALICE)));
    
            let coin = CoinGame::get_coin(&ALICE).unwrap();
    
            let toss_result = CoinGame::random_coin_side();
    
            // advance 10 blocks
            System::set_block_number(24);
    
            let toss_result2 = CoinGame::random_coin_side();
    
            assert_ok!(CoinGame::toss_coin(RuntimeOrigin::signed(ALICE), toss_result.clone()));
    
            let expected_event = RuntimeEvent::CoinGame(Event::CoinGuessed(ALICE, toss_result));
            assert_eq!(last_event(), expected_event);
            assert!(false);
        });
    }
```

Taking into consideration that my mock environment is set by the following function:

```rust
    pub fn new_test_ext() -> sp_io::TestExternalities {
        let t = frame_system::GenesisConfig::<Test>::default().build_storage().unwrap().into();
        let mut ext = sp_io::TestExternalities::new(t);
        ext.execute_with(|| System::set_block_number(14));
        ext
    }
```

Why I'm not getting the same randomness on my unit test and on the substrate node running?